# FakeItEasy mock interface not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mocking, fakeiteasy

I'm new to FakeItEasy and mocking in general.  I created a Visual Studio 2010 C# class library project.  I added references to the NUnit DLL and the FakeItEasy DLL.  I added "using" statements for both, then attempted to try some of the documentation examples.  My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using FakeItEasy.Core;
// ...
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TestLib
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tester
    {
        [Test] 
        public void SomeTest() 
        {
            ISomething mockThing = A.Fake<ISomething>(); 
            /*
            ...
             */
        }

    }
}
```

I get errors "*The type or namespace name 'ISomething' could not be found*" and *"The name 'A' does not exist in the current context."*

What am I missing?

Comment: Okay I solved one of the errors.  The message about "A" not existing was because I needed to add the namespace "FakeItEasy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is necessary to create the interfaces that are referred to in the mocks.  They are not auto-generated.

It is, however possible to specify additional interfaces to be implemented:

```
var foo = A.Fake<IFoo>(x => x.Implements(typeof(IComparable)).Implements(typeof(IFormattable)));
```